# Do Chromebooks that are part of Google's Enterprise Programme work for private individuals?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

I'm interested in buying a Chromebook, and have read that [the one I am interested in](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/professional-series/acerchromebook14forwork) is associated with Google's Enterprise offering.

Will this kind of Chromebook still work standalone, or do they need to be added to a corporate (Active) directory to work?

I am a private individual and the device I buy will never be connected to a corporate network.

Comment: Nothing on the product page indicates anything about Enterprise.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: I think it was mentioned in a video review. I'll try to find the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought the Chromebook in the above link, and it works perfectly as a standalone Chromebook linked to a standard Google account.